Don't understand the solution
Question from chapter 1 of Putnam and Beyond

Show that there does not exist a strictly increasing function $f :\mathbb N \to\mathbb N$ satisfying
$f (2) = 3$ and $f (mn) = f (m) f (n)$ for all $m, n \in\mathbb N.$

Solution
I don't understand the last part of the solution, specifically how it arrived at the conclusion: "But this would imply 65536=..."
On the other hand, why doesn't it suffice to say that since rationals are dense in the reals, there exists a rational number $\frac{v}{u}$ in between the values $\log_2 3$ and $\log_3 6$, a contradiction of the monotonicity of $f$ given that $\frac{v}{u}\gt \log_2 3 \text{ if and only if } \frac{v}{u}\gt \log_3 6$?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Your alternate argument assumes $\log_23\neq\log_36.$

The given argument assumes $3.2<1+\sqrt5,$ or equivalently, $2.2<\sqrt5.$ This can be seen since $2.2^2=4.84<5.$

Essentially, they are proving the result you merely assume.

Oh, yeah that makes sense because we can't assume they are equal

We have this related pair of inequalities
$$ a > b \iff a > c $$
(WLOG take $b < c$)
Suppose that $b < d < c$. Then $d$ is a counterexample to the above statement, so there cannot be such a $d$. Thus, in order for the above statement to be true, it follows that there are no values strictly between $b$ and $c$.
However,the density of the rationals means that there is always a rational number strictly between distinct real values $b$ and $c$. Thus, is $a \in \Bbb Q \subset \Bbb R$ and $b,c \in \Bbb R$, we must have that
$$ (a > b \iff a > c) \implies b = c $$
In our case, this provides the step from two inequalities about $v/u$ to the statement
$$ \log_2 3 = \log_3 6 $$
If this is not true, this leads to a contradiction with the monotonicity of $f$, which shows that such an $f$ cannot exist. And, of course, it's not true, but we are responsible for proving that.
Assuming you follow everything up until
$$ 2^{1+\sqrt{5}} = 9 $$
the only missing step is to note that
$$3.2 = 1 + 2.2 < 1 + \sqrt{5}$$
and so
$$2^{5\cdot 3.2} < 9^5$$
which can be shown by direct calculation to be false.

He is approximating the irrational number $1+\sqrt5$ from below by a multiple of $0.2,$ namely $1+2.2$ (it is easy to verify by hand that $2.2$ is less than the square root of 5 by computing its square, $4.84$). The advantage of a multiple of $0.2$ is that multiplying it by 5 turns it into an integer, making the power of 2 easy to evaluate.
Exponentiation (with a base greater than 1, such as 2) is an increasing function, so it preserves order.
The 5th power of 9 can be calculated by hand, no need for further approximations.
